# SQL CRASH WHEN I STARTED

Tags: sql, database, crash

I have a problem with SQL SERVER I finished the installation and when I run it it shows me a message on the screen indicating that SQL stopped working, I installed it more than three times and it always gives me the same error, could someone help me, I need to use my Databases without having to change machines.

Thank you very much,

[This is the error :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSqOh.png)

Comment: maybe you installed the wrong version of sql..  are you in 32-bit or 64-bit OS?

Comment: I have a 64-bit OS and i installed the 64-bit version

Comment: i think you will have to install the 32-bit... not all 64-bit OS requires 64-bit applications

Comment: Thanks, i will try